# TikZ plot dealing with infinities

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a couple of problems while drawing a picture with TikZ. The picture I would like to obtain is like the following:

[image: this one].

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,patterns}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\clip(0,0) rectangle (6,6);
\draw[thick] (3.,3.) circle ({pi/2});
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1};
\draw[thick,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=black] (3.,3.) circle ({rad(atan(\x))});
\begin{scope}[shift={(3,3)}]
\foreach \z in {0.5,1,2,3}
\draw [variable=\y,domain=-\z+0.001:\z-0.001] plot ({deg(\y)+90}:{rad(atan( (\x*(1-(cosh(\x*\y)/cosh(\x*\z))^2)^(-0.5)))});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I obtain is

[image]

I have two problems:

- I have infinities in my calculation. That gave all sort of problems, so I restricted the domain in the plot so that I don't include the singular point (which then is mapped to a finite value by the arctan function). However, in this way I cannot get to the proper value and the plots do not touch the outer circle.
- The plot lines are not smooth.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: By default when you draw something TikZ use 25 points. You can change this by putting for example `samples=300` in your `\draw` command. This will smooth the curve.

Comment: You can solve your first problem by cheating : make your circle a little bit smaller (and clip with it).

Comment: or if you want less accuracy but faster compile you can put less points (for example `samples=100`), but add `smooth` and play with `tension`.

Answer (score 10):

Takes a bit to compile but looks like it comes close. I used pgfplots to handle the plotting and infinity issues etc. It already provides a `polaraxis` environment so no need to do extra work. You can also invoke a gnuplot directive to get more precision. I would strongly recommend changing the colormap though. Even Matlab finally stopped using it in 2014b.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,pgfplots.polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[samples=200,grid=none,enlargelimits=false,
                  xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,axis y line={none}]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1};
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.15,0.3,...,3,pi}{
 \addplot[mesh,domain=-#1+1e-3:#1-1e-3,variable=\y,
          point meta=12-\plotnumofactualtype, % For color match
          point meta max=30] 
         ({deg(\y)+90},{rad(atan( (\x*(1-(cosh(\x*\y)/cosh(\x*#1))^2)^(-0.5)))});}
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the lines are not touching the boundary. A little bit smaller circle (with clip) will be ok. I have not investigated if this is a precision problem or something else, I'm just looking and admiring your picture !

Comment: @Kpym You can add `ymax=1.4`. Because it is an axis, it will limit the visible area.

Answer (score 7):

This is a cheating lesson (you can see my comments), not a real solution.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,patterns}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \clip (3.,3.) circle ({pi/2 - .05});
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1};
    \draw[thick,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=black] (3.,3.) circle ({rad(atan(\x))});
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3,3)}]
      \foreach[evaluate=\z as \c using .3*\z] \z in {.1,.3,...,3,3.14} {
        \definecolor{currentcolor}{hsb}{\c,1,1}
        \draw [variable=\y,domain=-\z+0.001:\z-0.001, smooth, samples=100, currentcolor] 
        plot ({deg(\y)+90}:{rad(atan( (\x*(1-(cosh(\x*\y)/cosh(\x*\z))^2)^(-0.5)))});
      }
    \end{scope}
    \draw[very thick] (3.,3.) circle ({pi/2 - .059});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** And here is a real solution using `atan2` to avoid infinity problems.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[thick,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=black] circle (pi/4);
    \foreach[
      evaluate=\z as \c using \z/180,
      evaluate=\z as \chz using cosh(rad(\z))]
      \z in {10, 20, ..., 180} {
        \definecolor{currentcolor}{hsb}{\c,1,1}
        \draw [variable=\y,domain=-\z:\z, smooth, samples=100, currentcolor]
            plot({\y + 90} : {rad(atan2(\chz, sqrt((\chz)^2 - (cosh(rad(\y)))^2)))});
      }
    \draw[very thick] circle (pi/2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]